# SQL query to find family collisions based on date value

Tags: sql-server-2008

Looking for a select statement to find records within a group of document based on `PARENTGROUPID` number, where date values from the child are inconsistent from that group. The parentgroup ID will always be the lowest recordnum from the group, if that helps.

For example. I have the following records

```
RecordNUM   ParentGroupID   Date
000001      000001          5/1/2014
000002      000001          5/1/2014
000003      000001          5/2/2014
000004      000004          11/2/2013
000005      000004          11/2/2013
000006      000006          1/23/2014
000007      000006          1/23/2014
000008      000006          1/23/2014
000009      000006          1/25/2014
```

I am trying to catch inconsistent dates as an example for groupID 00001 where date is 5/2/2014 for one of the child but the parent is 5/1/2014. The other group that should come up from the check is also groupID 00006 where the last child is dated 1/25/2014 instead of 1/23/2014

Comment: It's pretty basic sql; what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is really bad design. You need to normalize your database unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: @user3622204 -- While I agree the accepted answer can work, the `partition by` approach should have a much quicker execution plan.

Comment: @sgeddes Indeed. Looking at the execution plans your answer should perform better, although I wasn't expecting such a big difference that the plan showed for the simple except query - I would have thought partitioning would have been more costly that the set based approach using except, but I guess I was wrong. Good to know. +1 to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the `ParentGroupID` and `Date` and don't need the `RecordNUM` you can use the `EXCEPT` operator:

```
select parentgroupid, date from your_table 
except
select parentgroupid, min(date) 
from your_table
group by parentgroupid
```

This forms a set of all rows and subtracts the set that contains the min(date) for each ParentGroupID from it.

If you need the `RecordNUM` column too you can use the query above as a subquery in a join:

```
select * from your_table t1 
inner join (
  select parentgroupid, date from your_table 
  except
  select parentgroupid, min(date) 
  from your_table
  group by parentgroupid
) t2 on t1.ParentGroupID = t2.ParentGroupID and t1.Date = t2.Date
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9980/2)

Comment: BONUS I have the following sample SQL update query below to correct the resulting inconsistencies but I'm not sure it will work

UPDATE D1
SET D1.DATE = D2.Datefix 
FROM EDDSDBO.Document AS D1
INNER JOIN EDDSDBO.Document AS D2 ON
D1.Recordnum = D2.Recordnum
WHERE (D1.Recordnum <> D1.ParentGroupID)

Any ideas?

Comment: @user3622204 I've appended the SQL Fiddle to include an update statement that corrects the erroneous values to the min(date) for the parentgroupid; I added a select statement at the and that shows the altered table. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9980/5

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using `min over` to get the parent's date, then compare that to the child's date:

```
with cte as (
  select *, min(dt) over (partition by parentgroupid) mindt
  from yourtable
  )
select *
from cte 
where dt <> mindt
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c87cf/6)